# How do I interleave two lists or data in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to combine two lists in Google Spreadsheet so that the cells interleave.
Both lists have the same amount of elements.

So that:

```
1          A
2          B
3          C
```

becomes:

```
1
A
2
B
3
C
```

The closest I came up with is something like `JOIN({List A},{List B})`, but in this way the Elements of `List B` are only split by the first Element of `List A`.

It would be great if someone has an idea without any add-ons using only the built-in functions. Transposing and formatting is not that important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(A1:B&char(9)),char(9))))
```

(note that concatenate has a limit of 50000 characters)

or

```
=transpose(split(join(" ",query(transpose(A1:B),,50000))," "))
```

Where list A starts in A1, list B in B1.

Comment: Both suggestions worked just great. Thank you very, very much JPV!

Comment: Or with the undocumented function `FLATTEN` as `=FLATTEN(A1:B)`. In brief: Flatten flattens the selected array to 1D. The array is stored in row-major (C-style) order which means that it will naturally stack row-wise.

Comment: `FLATTEN` is the far superior function to use when dealing with string data for this scenario.